# how to go next page in javascript after checking the condition

Tags: javascript

how to go next page in javascript after checking the condition.

I am new student of  javascript ,so please tell me how to do this.sent one example  easy for learn .

Comment: `window.location.href = yourlandingpage`. Post some code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(conditionIsTrue){
    window.location.href = '...';
}
```

which will check if 'conditionIsTrue' is true, then send you to the URL you place in the next line.